# Refactor keyboard shortcuts in MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop

Are there keyboard bindings to the refactoring commands in MonoDevelop?

Comment: Which version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Answer (score 11):

**A direct answer**: Yes, there are.

**A bit more useful answer**: depending on what you're looking for, quick examples:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> is `quick fix` (given you've got [source analysis](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_3.0#Experimental_Source_Analysis) turned on)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> is `code generation` (properties, overrides, etc.)
- <kbd>F2</kbd> is `rename`

And, in case you're not aware, all the refactorings for the symbol you got under your cursor are available in the right-click context menu (available by pressing the relevant keyboard key, so it also kind of counts as a keyboard binding ;) )

Apart from that, you can look up and/or change all (or at least many, I'm not exactly sure) the bindings in `Options > Preferences > Key Bindings`.

Does the above answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

It depends which version of MonoDevelop you are using. With the late 2.x series then there were individual key bindings for "Create Method", "Extract Local Variable" and a few others (see [the documentation](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Refactoring)).

Renaming (including renaming files in the explorer view and renaming variables, classes or anything else in the text editor) is a separate key binding under the "Edit" section and defaults to shortcut key <kbd>F2</kbd>.

As of v3.x, these key-bindings seem to have disappeared. Edit > Preferences > Key Bindings still has a "Refactoring" section, but it now only lists Import Symbol, Quick Fix and Show Fixes (none of which I'd necessarily even call refactoring - they're more code completion features). Instead, the refactoring methods are all available [as "Quick Fixes"](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodevelop-list/2012-August/015036.html) (default: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when Source Analysis is turned on from Edit > Preferences > Other > Source Analysis).

The reason for the change appears to be that the refactoring mechanism has been overhauled and now relies on source analysis, but this isn't quite perfect yet and so isn't enabled by default. As they're part of the Quick Fix system then they've not been given separate key bindings (as I believe there are more of them now).

Answer (score 0):

For me, Source Analysis menu is: 
Tools>Option>Source Anyalysis (Under Text Editor) > Enable

Well it does make some changes to the Editor screen, it doesn't really give me useful suggestion for correction (auto fix) like Eclipse, regardless of whether I've press Alt+Enter.